# How to unselect a radio button in zk when no radioGroup is used

Tags: java, html, mvvm, zk, zul

Let say we have this code:

```
<window>    
   <radio selected="@bind(vm.value)" /> 
</window>
```

When we click this radio button it will get selected ...but clicking it again do not unselect it..

Is there a better approach other then binding the `onClick` and toggling it in java ?

Comment: I think a checkbox is more suitable than a radio button if you want such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

you create a method in java class just like `showVisibleRadio`  and check condition .

```
   <window>    
       <radio selected="@bind(vm.value)"   onCheck="@command('showVisibleRadio')"/> 
    </window>
```

//java code

```
  @Command
     public void  showVisibleRadio(){

       if (value.isChecked()){
       value.setChecked(false);
       }
       else{
       value.setChecked(true);
      }
    }
```